# How can I tell Phusion Passenger which python to use?

Tags: python, django, apache, passenger, wsgi

I'm using Phusion Passenger with a ruby app and I'd also like to set it up to work with an django appengine app I'm working on.

Googling for "passenger_wsgi.py" I was able to get the following very simple non-django app working on passenger:

passenger_wsgi.py:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
   response_headers = [('Content-type','text/plain')]
   start_response('200 OK', response_headers)
   return ['Hello World!\n']
```

However, if I add the line `import django.core.handlers.wsgi` into the mix, I get 'An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py'.  By printing out the sys.path I've discovered that at least part of the reason is because Passenger is using the wrong python installation on my machine.

How can I configure Passenger (on apache) to use `/opt/local/bin/python2.5` instead of the system default python?

Comment: Wow cool. I never know passenger also works with django.

Comment: I found this: https://gist.github.com/mpwoodward/3b446e573eb7b4d6f758c291c06f607e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that if I changed the hashbang at the first line of passenger's `request_handler.py` file to `#!/opt/local/bin/python2.5`, passenger used the correct python.  But surely there must be a better way than modifying passenger's distribution?

Comment: where could I find `request_handler.py` ?  I am using Passenger docker image.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the python interpreter via the `PassengerPython` variable in the server config, virtual host, directory, or .htaccess file.

apache: [PassengerPython](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerpython)

nginx: [passenger_python](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_python)

standalone: [--python](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--python-python)

Comment: This is the best (least hack-y) way.

Comment: This is it. This is nice and clear solution for Phusion Passenger / NginX / Flask combination. Given you have a Flask app called `app.py` and `app.conf` is your configuration file, you need to add e.g. `passenger_python /usr/local/bin/python3` line to the `server` section (context) there (or whatever your path to Python3 executable is).

Answer (score 3):

One trick is to include a line like this in your passenger_wsgi.py file:

```py
if sys.version < "2.4":  
     os.execl("/usr/bin/python2.4", "python2.4", *sys.argv)
```

or

```py
INTERP = "/usr/local/bin/python"  
    if sys.executable != INTERP:  
        os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
```

Each of these basically tells the environment to use your preferred python.