# Any way to get Phusion Passenger running in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passenger

I'm trying to get a Python 3 WSGI app running using Phusion Passenger. Using the info from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842336/how-can-i-tell-phusion-passenger-which-python-to-use), I can make Passenger use Python 3, but it does not seem possible to have a Python 3 app running with Passenger in Python 2.x (i.e. it seems both the app and Passenger must run in the same Python interpreter). Therefore I assume I need to make Passenger work in 3.x.

I ran 2to3 on Passenger's request_handler.py and then worked out the remaining runtime errors. However when I run the app, I just get a 502 with this error in the log:

> [error] 9839#0: *4 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: …, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "…"

The same app code does work with Passenger in Python 2.x, so I assume it's related to my 2to3 migration of request_handler.py. Below is the diff of my changes. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
27c26
< import traceback
---
> import exceptions, traceback
29c28
< from socket import SocketIO
---
> from socket import _fileobject
65c64
<                   except Exception as e:
---
>                   except Exception, e:
67c66
<                       sys.stderr.write(str(e.__class__) + ": " + str(e) + "\n")
---
>                       sys.stderr.write(str(e.__class__) + ": " + e.message + "\n")
84c83
<       buf = b''
---
>       buf = ''
92c91
<       buf = b''
---
>       buf = ''
99c98
<       headers = buf.split(b"\0")
---
>       headers = buf.split("\0")
117c116
<       env['wsgi.input']        = SocketIO(input_stream,'r',512)
---
>       env['wsgi.input']        = _fileobject(input_stream,'r',512)
155c154
<                       raise exc_info[0](exc_info[1]).with_traceback(exc_info[2])
---
>                       raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern answer:

You can specify the python interpreter via the PassengerPython variable in the server config, virtual host, directory, or .htaccess file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52582232/1630632

Answer (score -1):

Porting is rarely just about running 2to3, and it's definitely not about that in WSGI applications where the WSGI spec had to be slightly modified for Python 3. You'll need to firstly make any tests the application has (I hope it has) work under Python 3, and if you then have any remaining problems, the unfortunate fact is that you will have to debug them to figure out exactly what the problem is, so you can fix it.

A traceback could have been helpful, but it seems that PP swallows the tracebacks and outputs an error instead.

It is probably easier to use whatever WSGI server you used to develop the application instead.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is really about getting Passenger to run in Python 3, not about porting my app. I don't yet have an app developed; I'm simply trying to get started using Python 3 with Passenger. I have a Hello World running in Passenger with Python 2.6, but I can't get Passenger to run in Python 3.

Also for what it's worth, Passenger does print out tracebacks when they occur. That is how I fixed the runtime errors that I mentioned after running 2to3. There are no longer any explicit errors coming from Python.

Comment: @Derek: I understood your question, and I believe I answered it. Since you don't actually have the application developed yet, you do have another option: Use Python 2. But those are the three options: 1. Port Passenger (and that will take debugging which I can't do for you, you will have to figure out *why* that connection gets closed unexpectedly, there is no obvious reason why it should, or 2. Don't use Passenger, or 3. Don't use Python 3.